# Is $(\mathbb{R},+)$ isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_\omega$?

Tags: gr.group-theory, permutations, permutation-groups

Is $(\mathbb{R},+)$ isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_\omega$, the group of permutations of the set of non-negative integers $\omega$?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate, of some post here or MathSE. BtW you mean isomorphic as abstract groups, since it's clearly impossible with the usual topologies.

Comment: Actually the answer was already contained in the end [of my previous answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/301875/14094) to the same OP.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See Theorem 4.3 of [this paper](https://pure.tue.nl/ws/portalfiles/portal/1866721/597514.pdf) by De Bruijn. Any abelian group of order $2^\kappa$ can be embedded in $Sym(\kappa)$ when $\kappa$ is infinite. (There is also an [addendum](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82202896.pdf) to the paper which corrects some error in the proof.)

Comment: How does this address the question?

Comment: @KConrad quite immediately, just using $\kappa=\omega$. Actually this case is obvious from many standard facts. For instance, $G=PSL_2(\mathbf{Q}_p)$ acts faithfully on the vertex-set of its Bruhat-Tits tree, a countable set. Then $G$ contains subgroups isomorphic to $\mathbf{Q}_p$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbf{R}$ as abstract group. Actually this can be refined to show that every linear group over a field of cardinal $\le c$ acts faithfully on a countable set. Alternatively, $\mathbf{R}\simeq\mathbf{Q}^\mathbf{N}$ acts faithfully on $\mathbf{Q}\times\mathbf{N}$ in the obvious way.

Comment: $(\mathbb{R},+)$ is an abelian group of order $2^{\aleph_0}$ and so embeds in $S_\omega$ by the theorem I quoted. Unless I’m misreading something?

Comment: Oops, I misread $\kappa$ as $k$ and thought the answer was about abelian subgroups of order $2^k$ for each nonnegative integer $k$ instead of one subgroup of order $2^{\kappa}$.

Comment: @GabeConant You are not misreading - and thanks for your answer!

Comment: In the cited paper of de Bruijn, he mentions (p. 561) that the special case of the reals and Sym$(\omega)$ was proved by Karrass and Solitar a year earlier (1956).

Comment: I just had a look at Karrass and Solitar (1956) where it's made as an observation; the last line of my first comment is basically the same argument.